# How to let Material-UI input field fill toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling to get the material-ui app bar example to work as I would like to. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9wup7) (from Material-UI website).

**What I Am Trying To Achieve:**

What I am trying to achieve is to get the search field to grow all the way to the right (effectively taking the majority of the app bar no matter what screen size).

**What I Have Tried:**

I have tried using `flexGrow: 1` as follows which only grows the search bar slightly (not till the end):

```
search: {
  position: 'relative',
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
},
marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
marginLeft: 0,
width: '100%',
[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
  marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
  width: 'auto',
  flexGrow:1
},}
```

I have also tried setting `width: '100%'` instead of `'width: auto'` but that makes the Material-UI logo disappear.

Image of desired result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width: 'auto'` from your current code,

Add `minWidth` with title

```
title: {
  display: 'none',
  minWidth: '120px',                 // Add
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    display: 'block',
  },
},
search: {
  position: 'relative',
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
  },
  marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: '100%',                     // Keep
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    // width: 'auto',                // Remove
  },
},
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: that makes the search bar indeed bigger but makes the material-ui logo illegible. What I want is that the material ui logo is still legible (without the ellipsis).

Comment: @Keida Updated, and if it solved your problem, kindly upvote would be appreciated